# Two foreign keys pointing to the same table / model

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-5, model, eloquent

I have two models:

- TRUCK
- DRIVER

TRUCK has two fields which are FKs. `Driver (FK)` and `Driver2 (FK)`.

When I try to get the truck with driver and driver2, I get two same records.

```
    $truck = $this->instance->truck()->where('id', $id)
            ->with(['driver', 'driver2',])
            ->firstOrFail();
```

My Truck Model:

```
class Truck extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;       
    protected $table = 'trucks';
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public function driver()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Driver');
    }

    public function driver2()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Driver');
    }
```

My Driver Model:

```
class Driver extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;    
    protected  $table = 'drivers';
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public function truck()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Truck');
    }
```

I am still new to laravel and something I get stuck. Should I create another model instead maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default laravel will use default foreign key,

> Eloquent assumes the foreign key of the relationship based on the
>   model name [#Further reading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)

So both relation are pointing to the same **FK**, So you need to specify the foreign key as below

```
   return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Driver', 'Driver');
   return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Driver', 'Driver2');
```

Full code

```
class Truck extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;       
    protected $table = 'trucks';
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public function driver()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Driver', 'Driver');
    }

    public function driver2()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Driver', 'Driver2');
    }
```